# Running Python scripts in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I cannot get to open my Python scripts saved in default directory: *....\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts* in QGIS 3.0 Processing Toolbox. There is no folder called **Scripts** like in 2.18.

Anybody knows how to open my Python script in Processing Toolbox of 3.0?

[image: Processing Toolbox in QGIS 3.0 without Scripts folder]

Comment: If "Add script from file" does not load the script, there is probably an error in the code

Comment: In the interim you can run both 2.18 and 3.0 simultaneously on one machine.

Comment: @underdark♦ Thank you, that makes sense. But why can I load the same script in 2.18? Is there some unfinished work in 3.0 in that sense?

Comment: @Jakub Sisak GeoGraphics: But are the scripts for 3.0 compatible with 2.18? There are some processing tools that do not exist in 2.18?

Comment: No expert in Python - does the script require a specific version of Python? It is my understanding that QGIS 3 uses Python 3 and the older QGIS v 2.18 uses Python 2.7.5. I understand all plugins need to be re-written to work with QGIS 3. There may be syntax changes between the versions of the scripts as well? I am just brainstorming here...

Comment: Yes, you are right! QGUs 3.0 runs on Python 3. That is going to be the issue.